# 400 bad request when using open weather maps api geo location call?

Tags: javascript

I first use this code to get my geo location:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  long = position.coords.longitude;
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  $("#data").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long);
  });
}
```

Then I use the geo location to call API:

```
var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={+lat+}&lon={+long+}&appid=a85717f57b6bd30e011747de59dc3a60"
```

It returns code error 400, bad request.

Comment: Did you do any debugging at all?
I mean, you're passing nothing on that URL inside a String (lat for example).

Comment: I don't know, I just started learning using api call

Comment: Try to do a bit more of research before asking questions at Stackoverlfow.
Ask questions. Get answers. No chitchat.


There are variables inside your api string, the API (URL) specifically tells you that your lat variable is a non float variable, which means it expects a float number while you're just passing a word "lat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have not properly concatenated the variables lat and long into the URL.   Use `" + lat + "` rather than `{+lat+}` like this: `var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +lat+ "&lon=" +long+ "&appid=a85717f57b6bd30e011747de59dc3a60";`  that works for me.

Another potential issue may be scope; if your `var api` is outside of the if statement it won't know what the variables `lat and long` are.  One way around this is to declare those variables globally (outside the if statement).  Or move the  `var api` inside the statement.

Comment: Hey, I tried to use " +lat+ " to concatenate variable into the URL. I also declared api, long and lat globally. But I still get error 400 bad request.

Comment: Hey check this out, look in the console log and tell me if the link there works for you: https://codepen.io/tfantina/pen/pPPoXO

Comment: Hey I solved it! Turned out I used quotation marks inconsistently! I used single quotation marks for +lat+ and +long+ !